# Allow to view image in landscape in portrait-only app

Tags: image, ios5, uiimageview, orientation, segue

I am making an `iPhone` and `iPod` app that I will make in `portrait` mode only. There comes a point in the app where if the user touches a picture, it will make itself `fullscreen`. The way I do that is via a segue to another view controller, where a `UIImageView` takes the whole space. I would like to be able to rotate the device in `landscape` to view the picture in `landscape`.

How it that possible?

In a second phase: I would like to know how to make the view `fullscreen`, so the picture could fill the entire screen.

**Basically**: I want the picture to behave just like the twitter app. :)

Thanks

**EDIT**: here is the code in my Class to view the image

```
#import "ImageViewer.h"

@interface ImageViewer ()

@end

@implementation ImageViewer
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize image;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);

    self.imageView.frame = imageFrame;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = imageFrame.size;

}

- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    return self.imageView;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-  (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"rotate.");
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setImageView:nil];
    [self setScrollView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Comment: you resize the view frame... like that view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480) in iphone except iphone5....

Comment: How will that allow landscape only for the image, which is what I want?

Comment: Help please? I already resized the frame of the image view but the image doesn't rotate of doesn't go full screen

Comment: hi can you post some code pls for better understanding

Comment: I edited my post. I want to be able to rotate the device to view the image in landscape AND view it fullscreen.

Comment: _cpGraphView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; try this for full screen  or u just try yourView.frame=self.view.bounds; it will work

Comment: @Spynet: Neither of these lines work. But my biggest concern is how to allow landscape?